# Accessing NSWindow-like properties in Catalyst macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, uiwindow, mac-catalyst

I am thinking about porting my macOS app to Catalyst.

My app shows a transparent window (no title bar, clear background) on top of all other apps windows (dock included).
To do that, in the non-catalyst code I use:

```
window.isOpaque = false
window.hasShadow = false
window.backgroundColor = .clear
window.styleMask = .borderless
window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
window.level = .statusBar
```

Using UIKit, I was only able to remove the toolbar so far:

`window.titleBar.titleVisibility`

...But no clue about the other settings.

I plan to make the app available on the App Store in the future, but if the only way to do so is and hack with a private API, that's fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official API for doing that, but you can easily access the `NSWindow` instance and modify it directly. You can do that manually or using some library like [Dynamic](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) (Full disclosure: I'm the author):

```swift
let window = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(uiWindow)

window.isOpaque = false
window.hasShadow = false
window.backgroundColor = Dynamic.NSColor.clearColor
window.styleMask = 0 /*borderless*/
window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
window.level = 25 /*statusBar*/
```

Comment: Is this something which will work for the App Store as well or will my app get rejected ?

Comment: I didn't try to submit an app that uses the library yet, but since every API it uses is documented I don't see a reason for rejection.

Answer (score 1):

I have some success removing the close button on Catalyst by calling a function from the `viewDidAppear()`. I called it `AppDelegate().disableTitleBarButtons()`. Has to be from view did appear.

AppDelegate().disableTitleBarButtons() is as follows

```
func disableTitleBarButtons() {
        func bitSet(_ bits: [Int]) -> UInt {
            return bits.reduce(0) { $0 | (1 << $1) }
        }

        func property(_ property: String, object: NSObject, set: [Int], clear: [Int]) {
            if let value = object.value(forKey: property) as? UInt {
                object.setValue((value & ~bitSet(clear)) | bitSet(set), forKey: property)
            }
        }

        // disable full-screen button
        if  let NSApplication = NSClassFromString("NSApplication") as? NSObject.Type,
            let sharedApplication = NSApplication.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication") as? NSObject,
            let windows = sharedApplication.value(forKeyPath: "windows") as? [NSObject]
        {
            for window in windows {
                let resizable = 4
                property("styleMask", object: window, set: [], clear: [resizable])
                let fullScreenPrimary = 7
                let fullScreenAuxiliary = 8
                let fullScreenNone = 9
                property("collectionBehavior", object: window, set: [fullScreenNone], clear: [fullScreenPrimary, fullScreenAuxiliary])
            }
        }
    }
```

Where is says let resizable = 4,
Change to 3 for no Maximise,
Change to 2 for No minimise,
Change to 1 of No Close button.

Play with the other numbers or stylemask settings also. Good luck